# SQL unique constraints evaluation/checking order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-constraint

If I have one table in SQL Database with two unique constraints, is there a specific order for the unique constraints to be checked/evaluated, and if there is any; is there a way to configure the order (precedence) in which the constraints are evaluated.

Edit: 
I have a stored procedure that inserts records to DB table with two unique constraints 'A' and 'B', the stored procedure checks which unique constraint was violated (if any) and performs a certain action accordingly.
I don't know if this is valid at all for sql servers, but when I create constraint 'A' before Constraint 'B', constraint 'A' is evaluated before constraint 'B' and vice versa. so is there any relation whatsoever between the order of creating the unique constraints and the order of checking/evaluating them.

Comment: Why would order matter for unique constraints?

Comment: unique constraint on col1, col2 is equivalent to unique constraint on col2, col1. The order doesn't matter. 11g on wards, the order doesn't matter even with the index, if that's what you are looking for

Comment: @DStanley I have a stored procedure that inserts data to this table, I want to check which unique constraint was violated so I can take a specific action for each one when it is violated and one I want to check always first.

Comment: @Ankit I have two unique constraint not one on two columns

Comment: There's no *guarantee* on which unique constraint will be reported as being violated if multiple constraints have been violated - which I guess is what you're asking.

Comment: If you want that much control you'll likely have to implement it yourself with triggers.  If the data violates one constraint it will be rejected - it doesn't matter what order they are checked in and it will not check the other constraint also.